# MFC - Copy a directory, it's subfolders and files

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, directory, copy

How do you copy a directory, subfolders and it's files? CopyFile doesn't allow wildcards, MoveFileEx works but the source directory is of course, "moved" not actually "copied"

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks... here's a better way though... simple and easy... 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/alexfileoperations.aspx